# How to include svn revision number with the snapshot during maven build

Tags: maven

I'm trying to upload the artifact `"web-1.0.0-BUILD-20151030.030449-9.war"` to the artifactory repository, which works fine. But i want include the svn revision number too with the snapshot. can any one help me . I tried `<finalName>` tag which is working during the build of WAR file, but it's not working during distribution Management builds the artifact to upload to artifactory repostiory.

```
<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
         <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maven is trying to tell you something. The reason why this is hard to do, is that Maven resolves artifacts using 5 coordinates: `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`, `classifier` and `packaging/type` (the 2 last ones are used more rarely than the others).

Let's say you request a dependency of `org.example:my-dep:1.0-SNAPSHOT`, and you have 5 different snapshots mapped under those coordinates.

How is Maven going to know which version you want? Remember, resolution uses the 5 coordinates, **only**. It's one thing knowing during *deployment* what revision you to want to use, but it's another thing determining during *resolution* what you might have meant is the correct version to resolve to.

Normally you would like the latest, which is why we have `maven-metadata.xml` that is automatically downloaded and parsed so that Maven can figure out which one of your N versions under `org.example:my-dep:1.0-SNAPSHOT` is the latest. But this is already done for you.

I strongly recommend that you put the revision number in `MANIFEST.MF` and call it a day. That way, it's quite easy for everyone else to determine which revision the snapshot was built on. Most IDEs allow you to browse the contents of a dependency in the project's tree view.

Comment: Side note: refer to [MDEPLOY-93 JIRA bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEPLOY-93) which is "Not A Problem" to see additional explanations.

Comment: @Tunaki, excellent tip. And straight from the source, no less.